# Not able to open my app to public network

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-ingress

I have a simple node API app, which runs using Mongo DB.
I want to deploy it using Kubernetes.
I want to keep node and MySQL both in separate namespaces.
I have managed to run MongoDB in another namespace and node app in another namespace.Node app connects to MongoDB using a fully-qualified-domain name (`db.namespace.svc.cluster.local`).
but, now I want to open my node app to the public so that it can be accessed over the internet.
I have tried to create a nodeport service in the namespace where the node app resides, but when I connect to service on nodeport using a browser, nothing happens. Service hostname also doesn't resolve. But, when when I curl this nodeport service from a pod from the same namespace, then it gives the correct output.
What is the issue? Please help.

Comment: You should connect that port on any of your Kubernetes node address (can be found in kubectl get nodes -o wide) - services FQDN are local to your cluster, they can not be used from an external workstation. Assuming your nodes are on your LAN, or that they to have public IPs attached.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have figured out theproblem.
problem is with acloudguru's lab environment.They have opened port 30080 on worker nodes,and I was using nodePort service without provideing a nodePort value,hence it was opening a random port which was not allowed.When,I am using 30080 as nodePort,and then try to connect it,application works fine.